# Higher spins elementary particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higher-spin

Lorentz invariance requirement of theory imposes the absense of interactions between spin 3 and higher spins bosons and arbitrary field (like spin $\frac{1}{2}$ fermions etc) at least in infrared limit. Thus higher integer spin fundamental fields are invisible even if they exist.

But what about higher spin elementary fermions? Does some theorem exist which explains their invisibility?

Comment: Have you looked at, e.g., the issues of the [Rarita-Schwinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : No, I haven't.

Comment: That's the Weinberg-Witten theorem.

Comment: @MengCheng : but how this theorem eliminates higher spin fermions?

Comment: Where in Weinberg-Witten theorem does it assume integer spins?